# htaccess subdomain redirect when specific script is called

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I need when an specific page is called with a subdomain it redirects to www.

I can give you an example:

nuevoleon.domain.com/empresa/

I need that the correct url for SEO purposes is:

[www.domain.com/empresa](http://www.domain.com/empresa)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^nuevoleon\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ empresa(/|$) http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```